# C# RegEx Multiline - Need to get specific text between pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have a multiline text string, as given below:

```
Policy NO: 236511116, Jhon Mark
Commencement Date: 28/02/2001 Age: 24, (—)
Plan: - Life Plan (r.No. 111)
Policy Term: 20 (Premium payment term : 15)
Premium (JIs.)t - 1,531.00 payable Quarterly
```

I am looking to extract following texts:

```
236511116 - Its a number which comes after text "Policy NO:" and before (,)

Jhon Mark - which comes after "," and before line break and its last word in 1st line

20 - which comes after "Policy Term: " and before "("

15 - which comes after "term : " and before ")"

1,531.00 - which comes after "Premium some chars - " and before "payable"
```

The before and after texts are fixed and will never change, so they can be used as search patterns. Texts to be searched can be changed and can be up to any length.

Please help and ignore my earlier question regarding RegEx.

Thanks

Comment: So... you want us to do your job? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Looking for a solution, I am a php guy working to fix a small c# utility problem and RegEx always bugged me a lot !!

Comment: Looking for a solution suggest you have tried something. If you did try, we can help you find what what you are doing wrong. If we just hand you over the solution, not only you will be just as lost next time, you also put a piece of code you don't understand in the code base and you will get bugs that you can't fix if the format changes a tiny bit: what happens if someone corrects the extra space after "term"? Oups, the magic formula kindly provided by Floris will fail and the search will return empty. It works... until someone fixes that typo. Take the time to understand, it's your job.

Comment: Actually till now what I tried was, I replaced line breaks with some identifier like "vvv" or "~" and made it to one line string and then tried searching with pattern starting with "vvv" and ending with "vvv" but that did not work.

Comment: I meant posting the actual code you tried to run.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex extracts all the elements you were after:

```
(?:Policy NO: (\d+), (.*)$|Policy Term: (\d+) .*Premium payment term : (\d+)|Premium .* ([0-9,.]+) payable .*)
```

You can see this at work, with an explanation, at http://regex101.com/r/iN8oB5

Let me know if you still have questions after checking out the link.

Comment: Thanks for help. I have tried this solution using :

Regex m = new Regex("(?:Policy NO: (\\d+), (.*)$|Policy Term: (\\d+) .*Premium payment term : (\\d+)|Premium .* ([0-9,.]+) payable .*)", RegexOptions.Multiline);

 But it returns 3 values :

 "Policy NO: 236511116, Jhon Mark", "236511116", "Jhon Mark"